# How to integrate progress bar in transformation of xml file using javax.xml.transform package?

Tags: xml-parsing, progress-bar, xslt

I am using javax.xml.transform package to transform huge XML file... This process takes lot of time.. and end user won't be able to see the progress. Is there any way to integrate progress bar with transformation process.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this kind of thing by reporting how much of the input file has been read so far. For example, wrap the `InputStream` that you're reading the input XML file from in a `javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream`, and then have `javax.xml.transform` read from that.

The pattern my colleagues used when the input came from a remote URL was like this:

```
URLConnection c = new URL(url).openConnection();
ProgressMonitorInputStream pm = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(parentComponent,
                "Transforming XML", c.getInputStream());
pm.getProgressMonitor().setMaximum(c.getContentLength());

// now read from 'pm'
```

This isn't the same as reporting your transformation progress, but as long as the transformation doesn't wait until it has read the entire file before producing output, it should be close.